# Как из Angular передать параметр в контроллер Spring Boot

Tags: http, rest, spring-boot, angular

Как правильно передать параметр из `RequestMapping` в Angular контроллер. Нужен вид `"http://localhost:8080/api/999555"` (параметр без `'='`)
Разумеется сейчас в контроллере у меня не верно. Подскажите правильный синтаксис.

**Spring Контроллер:**

```
@RequestMapping("/api/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Optional<SomeModel> redirectUi(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return testService.findById(id);
}
```

**Angular Контроллер:**

```
var app = angular.module("boot", []);
app.controller("AppCtrlCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.somemodel= [];

$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/{id}').then(function(response) {
    console.log("get");
    $scope.somemodel= response.data;
});
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Правильно:

```
@GetMapping("/api/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Collection<SomeModel> redirectUi(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return testService.findById(id);
}
```

Контроллер:

```
var app = angular.module("boot", []);
app.controller("AppCtrlCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.somemodel= [];

$scope.id = -1;

$http.get('api/'+$scope.id).then(function(response) {
    console.log("get");
    $scope.somemodel= response.data;
});
});
```